# Hatcher exercise 43c, section 2.2: If $X$ is a CW complex with finitely many cells in each dimension, then $H_n(X;G)$ is a direct sum...

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Below is the question. I will briefly describe how I solved parts a and b, then say why I'm stuck on c. There are other questions on this site which address this exercise, but none dealing with part c (to my knowledge).

> a. Show that a chain complex of free abelian groups $C_n$ splits as a direct sum of subcomplexes $0 \to L_{n+1} \to K_n \to 0$ with at most two non-zero terms.

> b. In case the groups $C_n$ are finitely generated, show there is a further splitting into summands $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ and $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{m}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$.

> c. Deduce that if $X$ is a CW complex with finitely many cells in each dimension, $H_n(X;G)$  is the direct sum of the following groups: 1. a copy of $G$ for each $\mathbb{Z}$ summand of $H_n(X)$ 2. a copy of $G/mG$ for each $\mathbb{Z}_m$ summand of $H_n(X)$ and 3. a copy of the kernel of $G \stackrel{m}{\to} G$ for each $\mathbb{Z}_m$ summand of $H_{n-1}(X)$.

Here is a sketch of my proofs for a. and b.:

a. Because everything is free abelian, $0 \to \text{Ker}( \partial) \to C_n \to \text{Im}(\partial) \to 0$ splits, so we can write $C_n \cong \text{Ker}( \partial) \oplus \text{Im}(\partial)$. Decomposing each chain group in this way and piecing together the maps gives the decomposition we're looking for.

b. Fix some (finite, by assumption) bases of $K_n$ and $L_{n+1}$. Let $A$ denote the matrix of $\partial$ with respect to these bases. Then we can use the smith normal form to write $A' = SAT$, where $A'$ is diagonal. Multiplication by $S$ and $T$ amounts to a change of basis in the domain a nd codomain. Then with respect to these new bases, we get the decomposition we're looking for.

Part c.

There are two problems with the above proof for arbitrary coefficients: 1. $\text{Im}(\partial)$ needn't be free, and therefore $0 \to \text{Ker}( \partial) \to C_n \to \text{Im}(\partial) \to 0$ needn't split. 2. I can't use smith normal form for arbitrary $G$. I don't think the proof of part c goes through exactly these steps, but I also can't see how to use the previous parts to solve the problem.

Comment: I believe the intent is to use (a) and (b), not to reprove them with different coefficients. The cellular chain complex for $X$ (with integer coefficients) will be of the form in part (b); what happens when you tensor that with $G$?